# Get data from three tabbed activity

Tags: android, tabbed

I am using tabbed activity and have three layouts and I wonder how its done when I want to get the data from all the tabbed activities are not in the view.

They all have different layouts so I cant use "findViewById" to retrive the data thats not in the view.

I thought I was smart and maybe i chould use "findViewById(android.R.id.content)".

Comment: Wasn't TabActivity deprecated in API level 13? :/
Regarding your question, why don't you just save the data you need in the Application class or some sort of resource available for you from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's fine, it uses fragments.

Comment: Ok. So is there any good way of pass data between fragments.

Comment: Keep in mind that the only 2 fragments are saved by default, so if you need the data, change it to 3.

Comment: Where do I change the defaults

Comment: You shouldn't pass the data between them, you need to pass the data to the activity, and pass it from there

Comment: If it's using ViewPager, then you can use:
setOffscreenPageLimit, and set it to 2